# write a trigger to disallow an employee joining between 6PM and 10 AM on weekdays

Tags: plsql, database-trigger

```
CREATE TABLE JOINING_DETAILS(EMPNAME VARCHAR2(20),HIREDATE DATE);


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TERW
BEFORE INSERT ON JOINING_DETAILS
FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN 

    IF to_char(:NEW.HIREDATE,'HH24' ) BETWEEN 18  AND 24 
    AND to_char(:NEW.HIREDATE,'HH24' ) BETWEEN 00  AND 10 
    THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20037,'NOT BETWEEN 6 PM TO 10 AM');
    END IF;
END;
```

trigger executed but i try to insert value for timing 20 it insert into joining_details table.....

```
INSERT INTO JOINING_DETAILS VALUES('PANDI',TO_DATE('20','HH24') );
```

how can i overcome this....

Answer (score 1):

```
IF to_char(:NEW.HIREDATE,'HH24' )BETWEEN 18  
AND 24 AND to_char(:NEW.HIREDATE,'HH24' ) BETWEEN 00  AND 10 THEN
```

should be

```
IF to_char(:NEW.HIREDATE,'HH24' )BETWEEN 18  AND 24 
OR to_char(:NEW.HIREDATE,'HH24' ) BETWEEN 00  AND 10 THEN
```

(OR not AND)

BTW I realise this is probably a class exercise in writing triggers, but if the rule is that the hire date can **never** be between those times then it would be better implemented as a check constraint.

Comment: @Ramapandian - if this answer helped you should accept and/or upvote it. Accepted answers improve the value of StackOverflow as a resource for future Seekers.